# Passing local functions  to setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout, local-variables

I have written the following function.

```
function obj()
{
     this.a;
}
obj.prototype.catch = function()
{
    alert('Catched')
}
obj.prototype.do = function()
{
    alert('called');
}
```

What i need is, to call  obj::catch()   after obj::do() is called and the call must be performed from inside obj::do() 
So how to pass the local function of obj to setTimeout

i have tried

```
obj.prototype.do = function()
 { 
     window.setTimeout('"'+this.catch+'()"',1000);
     alert('called');
 }
```

It does not worked
Then i tried

```
 obj.prototype.do = function()
 { 
     window.setTimeout('"'+this+'.catch()"',1000);
     alert('called');
 }
```

which gave me the following error on Chrome console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

So i tried the following dirty method(is it really dirty ?)

```
 obj.prototype.do = function()
 { 
     this.pid = randomVal(100);
     window['temp'+this.pid] = this;
     window.setTimeout("temp"+this.pid+".catch();",1000);
     alert('called');
 }
 function randomVal(bound)//returns a random number between 0 and <bound>
 {
       return (Math.floor(Math.random()*(bound)));
 }
```

That worked.

so why the first two methods not worked.Is there any other way to do the same thing without global variables..
The second method and last method are almost similar .But why am i gettng the error in second method..?
The worked code can be found here
http://jsfiddle.net/jXhAs/

Answer (score 8):

Don't pass strings to `setTimeout` … ever.

```
var self = this; // Because the scope will change
setTimeout(function () { self.catch() },1000);
```

Or if you are using JS 1.8.5:

```
setTimeout(this.catch.bind(this),1000);
```

You can [read more about `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: why not to pass strings?Is there any performance degradation and why?

Comment: i think you may be overwriting `window.self` with that variable declaration.

Comment: @JinuJD — They are hard to debug, slow, break scope and can cause security problems if user data gets into them.

Comment: @jbabey — I'm masking it in the local scope. That isn't a problem as nothing else is using it. A different variable name can be used. `self` and `that` are common conventions.

Answer (score 5):

You should pass a **function** to `setTimeout` (not a string):

Example:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    self.catch();
},1000);
```

Comment: You really shouldn't create a new, global object when you can keep a local reference.

Comment: This won't work anyway. `this` isn't the variable you want (because the scope has changed) and strings don't have a `catch` method.

Answer (score 1):

use a closure

```
obj.prototype.do = function()
{ 
     window.setTimeout((function(that){
        return function(){
            that.catch();
        };
     })(this),1000);
     alert('called');
}
```

Comment: There is no need to introduce *another* anonymous function when we can just create a locally scoped variable in the `do` function.

Comment: @Quentin: Funny, that's exactly what Neals' example does (if you imagine `obj.prototype.do = function(){}` around his code), yet you criticize him for that .. I guess somebody is hunting for acceptance here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why go through all of this effort, just pass the function.

```
function obj() {
    this.a;
}
obj.prototype.
catch = function() {
    alert('Catched')
}
obj.prototype.do = function() {
    setTimeout(this.
    catch, 1000);
}

var test = new obj();
test.do();​
```

Comment: This will break the reference to the object that is available inside `catch` via the `this` keyword. The example code doesn't use it, but it is clearly a heavily simplified example (since the function does nothing except fire an alert) and the real code probably depends on it.